# Azure DevOps hosted agents NuGet dependency version behaviour

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I have a build that seems to behave differently whether I send it to a hosted agent in the cloud or to an on-premise agent. The solution being built has projects exclusively using `<PackageReference>`, and the solution is being built using the new-ish `msbuild /restore` function. The specific way in which it behaves differently is that on the on-premise agent, the NuGet restore generates a bunch of warnings like this:

`##[warning]IQ.Core.Update\6.0.0\IQ.Core.Update.Services\IQ.Core.Update.Services.csproj(0,0): Warning NU1603: IQ.Enterprise.Activation.Model 6.0.8 depends on IQ.Framework (>= 6.8.0) but IQ.Framework 6.8.0 was not found. An approximate best match of IQ.Framework 6.8.1 was resolved.`

There are in fact much newer versions of IQ.Framework available from our internal package server.

Running the same build, the cloud agent does not generate these warnings. Is it possible that the cloud agents come pre-configured with a NuGet.config that overrides the default behaviour by setting "dependencyversion" to "Highest"? Or is there perhaps something different on the hosted agents that causes warning 1603 to be suppressed??

A previous incarnation of this build running on TeamCity also did not log these types of warnings, and I'm pretty sure our TeamCity agents didn't have any special NuGet configuration.

I am worried about whether the builds on the on-premise agent might actually be functionally different than the cloud agent, and the earlier TeamCity builds, if it's building against different versions of referenced packages.

Comment: What version of NuGet is your on-prem server using? Does it match the version being used on the hosted agent?

Comment: How do I check what NuGet version is implicated in MSBuild /restore? Or does the question not make sense in that case?

Comment: Please make sure you've added the url of internal package server in nuget.config file, and there exists the 6.8.0 version of that package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... depends on IQ.Framework (>= 6.8.0) but IQ.Framework 6.8.0 was not
>   found. An approximate best match of IQ.Framework 6.8.1 was resolved.

This warning always occurs when restore process can't find **one specific version** of referenced package. And it indicates that the `IQ.Enterprise.Activation.Model-6.0.8` in on-premise agent's cache has something like these in its xx.nuspec file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency id="IQ.Framework" version="6.8.0" />
</dependencies>
```

> Azure DevOps hosted agents NuGet dependency version behaviour

After the long discussion with **Jonathan** we've confirmed that this strange behavior resulted from the different content of the `IQ.Enterprise.Activation.Model 6.0.8` in both agents. Though they're same version 6.0.8, their `xx.nuspec` file actually have different dependencies. In local agent it should be `<dependency id="IQ.Framework" version="6.8.0" />` while in cloud agent it's apparently not `6.8.0`. So this warning occurs in local machine but not occurs when using cloud agent.(The 6.8.0 is not available for both two agents)

Comment: The packages are coming from Azure Artifacts, and the NuGet restore is being done via MSBuild's `/restore` function. The feed is being specified by passing `/p:RestoreAdditionalProjectSources=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/iqmetrix/_packaging/iqmetrix/nuget/v3/index.json` into MSBuild, and authentication is handled using `NuGetAuthenticate@0` in the Azure DevOps Build Pipeline, which as I understand sets up a credentials provider specifically to intercept Azure Artifacts URLs and supply an access token. In my testing, the exact same build definition is being sent to both kinds of agents.

Comment: The raw build log from the test that was sent to a hosted agent does not contain "6.8.0" or "6.8.1" anywhere. The NuGet restore downloads & installs IQ.Framework version 6.8.2.

Comment: We are in the process of transitioning from an internal ProGet server to Azure Artifacts, and have automation in place that ensures both servers always have exactly the same packages. As I write this, packages can no longer be directly posted to the ProGet server, and I believe a regular task checks for new packages posted to Azure Artifacts and posts them to ProGet server. In any case, this build configuration should at this point no longer be touching the ProGet server for anything.

Comment: (So when I wrote that the internal server has much newer versions of IQ.Framework, it is basically identical to stating that the Azure Artifacts feed has much newer versions.)

Comment: Just thought to search for 1603 rather than the version number in question, and it does not appear anywhere in the log (except, by chance, in the fractional seconds portion of one of the line timestamps).

Comment: @JonathanGilbert Hi friend, please consider deleting the first comment above or replacing the Organization Name with OrgName to protect your personal data! like: /p:RestoreAdditionalProjectSources=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json

Comment: I'll test with your further info and come back here later today:)

Comment: I created this chat room regarding your second-to-last comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204384/discussion-between-jonathan-gilbert-and-lance-li-msft

Comment: As per the chat, it has been discovered that the on-premise agents have a different `.nuspec` cached for the IQ.Enterprise.Activation.Model package. If you'd like to put this into an answer to this question, I'll happily accept it :-)

Comment: Looks like my guess in chat is right, hh. Glad to know it helps, I will update the answer later this morning:)

Comment: @JonathanGilbert Answer updated, feel free to let me know if it needs any edit. Thx!